# Task Scheduler response (0x1) when copy file to map disk

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I write code to backup file to Map disk. It worked when I run it manual (created zip file and copy file to map disk).

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set CUR_HH=%time:~0,2%
if %CUR_HH% lss 10 (set CUR_HH=0%time:~1,1%)
set CUR_NN=%time:~3,2%
set CUR_SS=%time:~6,2%
set CUR_MS=%time:~9,2%
set SUBFILENAME=web2_%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%
md C:\Backup\"%SUBFILENAME%"
md C:\Backup\"%SUBFILENAME%"\05_SOHOA_HOSOLUUTRU
XCOPY "E:\Data_SoHoa\05_SOHOA_HOSOLUUTRU" "C:\Backup\%SUBFILENAME%\05_SOHOA_HOSOLUUTRU" /E
md C:\Backup\"%SUBFILENAME%"\05_SOHOA_HOSOLUUTRU_API
XCOPY "E:\Data_SoHoa\05_SOHOA_HOSOLUUTRU_API" "C:\Backup\%SUBFILENAME%\05_SOHOA_HOSOLUUTRU_API" /E
md C:\Backup\"%SUBFILENAME%"\DATA
XCOPY "E:\Data_SoHoa\DATA" "C:\Backup\%SUBFILENAME%\DATA" /E
XCOPY "E:\Data_SoHoa\setup-TcpServerService.exe" "C:\Backup\%SUBFILENAME%\" /X
set PATH=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\
SETX MYPATH "%PATH%"
7z a C:\"%SUBFILENAME%".zip C:\Backup\"%SUBFILENAME%"
set copyfile = C:\%SUBFILENAME%.zip
COPY "C:\%SUBFILENAME%.zip" "Z:\Backup\TLAM_sohoa\%SUBFILENAME%.zip"
```

Then I setup Task Scheduler to auto run this bat script. It created zip file, but not copy this zip file to map disk and return (0x1) result.

Here is my setup

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if rhe task is run when no user is logged on there may not be mapped disks. try to use unc path to disk resource, or map the disk in your batch file, ie using `pushd \\...` also be sure that the account under it is run, have enough privileges to that resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to post this as a rewritten example. It formulates the date string in a none locale/PC dependent manner, reduces repetetive and unnecessary commands, replaces the deprecated `XCopy` with `RoboCopy` and uses `PushD` to create a temporary mapping to your server location for the final copy command.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SubFileName="
For /F "Tokens=1-6Delims=/: " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
)Do If Not Defined SubFileName Set "SubFileName=web2_%%A%%B%%C-%%D%%E%%F"
Set "CopyFile=C:\%SubFileName%.zip"
For %%A In ("05_SOHOA_HOSOLUUTRU" "05_SOHOA_HOSOLUUTRU_API" "DATA"
)Do RoboCopy "E:\Data_SoHoa\%%~A" "C:\Backup\%SubFileName%\%%~A" /E
RoboCopy "E:\Data_SoHoa" "C:\Backup\%SubFileName%" "setup-TcpServerService.exe" /CopyAll
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%CopyFile%" "C:\Backup\%SubFileName%"
PushD "\\server…\Backup\TLAM_sohoa"
Copy "%CopyFile%"
PopD
```

Just modify `server…` on line `10` to the UNC path of the location, which after logon would be, associated with `Z:`